# Executar migrations de um outro BD

Tags: php, laravel

Copiei os *migrations* de um outro BD para o meu. Dentro da *database/migrations*.

Qual o comando que uso no terminal para executar eles um por um, ou seja, individualmente ?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta o comando o comando:

`php artisan migrate --path="app/database/migrations/my_single_migration"`

<sub>Fonte: [SOen: running-one-specific-laravel-4-migration-single-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102197/running-one-specific-laravel-4-migration-single-file)</sub>

---

E olhando a documentação, da para fazer mais:

Executando todas as migrações pendentes

```
php artisan migrate
```

Executando todas as migrações pendentes para um caminho

```
php artisan migrate --path=app/foo/migrations
```

Executando todas as migrações pendentes para um pacote

```
php artisan migrate --package=vendor/package
```

<sub>Fonte: [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations)</sub>